# find element_by(by="tagName", value="body")

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, element, webbot

I Have a selenium bot I'm working on that works fine.
But I can't find the accurate syntax I shall use to grep the body element.
To reach an element I generally just use something like this:

```
canvas = driver.find_element("id", "canvas")
```

But for the body element, no one of the regular syntax works. I've tried:

```
find element_by("tagName", "body")
find element_by(by="tagName", value="body")
```

and different versions of tag_name, tagName, and so forth. I Can't use the By. since I have not imported it yet, which is a piece of cake anyway, but should it be necessary and would that help?

Answer (score 0):

i suggest to use xpath `find_element_by_xpath()` as it is well known and comparably easy to use.

For a first introduction have a look at:

[W3-Schools_xpath_tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp)

For identifiying the HTML elements see:

[octoparse_locate_xpath](https://www.octoparse.com/blog/how-to-find-xpath-to-locate-data-in-a-web-page)

And for you future xpath´s there is this cool cheatsheet:

[devhints_xpath](https://devhints.io/xpath)

Comment: Thx!, saw it worked with the By class to - but prefer not importing more than i need (: This suits me mutch better.

Comment: Thats fine it takes a while to get used to xpath. Note: to use xpath with selenium webdriver there are no extra imports neccessary and it is also possible to use the class attribute in combination with xpath.